# What is the name of this field in Bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies

**My tex**

```
@article{trachtenberg,
    author = {Trachtenberg, E.A.},
    title = {SVD of Frobenius matrices for approximate and multiobjective signal processing tasks},
    note = {E.F. Deprettere, Ed. SVD and Signal Processing},
    publisher = {Elsevier North-Holland, Amsterdam/New York},
    year = {1988},
    pages = {331-345}
}
```

**What is/are the name(s) of the field(s) *in E.F. Deprettere, Ed., SVD and Signal Processing*?**

This is the cite:

[image]

I think **note** is not the right field.

Comment: Is this in an anthology? If so, use <at>incollection rather than <at>article. Then you can use the fields editor, booktitle, publisher and address. [Sorry, the system won't let me use the @ more than once.]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Related to the following page I guess the entry should be:

http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=107317

```
@incollection{Trachtenberg:1989:SVD:107302.107317,
 author = {Trachtenberg, E.},
 chapter = {Singular Value Decomposition of Frobenius Matrices for Approximate and Multi-objective Signal Processing Tasks},
 title = {SVD and Signal Processing},
 editor = {Deprettere, Ed F.},
 year = {1988},
 isbn = {0-444-70439-6},
 pages = {331--345},
 numpages = {15},
 url = {http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=107302.107317},
 acmid = {107317},
 publisher = {North-Holland Publishing Co.},
 address = {Amsterdam, The Netherlands, The Netherlands},
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for showing me how to cite these correctly!